# Redirect to page if cookie is not found

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

If a cookie for example

```
visited
```

was not found, is it possible to make the page redirect to

```
/welcome
```

I have started off with this:

```
    function getCookie(visited) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = visited + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
} 

function doSomething() {
    var myCookie = getCookie("visited");

    if (myCookie == null) {
        window.location.href = '/welcome';
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Have I done this correctly becuase it is not working correctly on my website.

Comment: Can you share some code on what you have started?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Added the code in Loaf

Comment: I'll counter a downvote since you added code. Are you ever calling `doSomething()`?

Comment: That may be where I have gone wrong

Comment: This is really something that should be handled server side, and not in Javascript. Javascript can be disabled. Are you using a server side language?

Comment: I'm just using HTML, Javascript or PHP if possible

Comment: PHP is what you should use soit can't be edited client side or if javascript is disabled. I think it is a lot easier to use as well for cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try PHP:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) {
    header("Location: page.php");
}
```

Comment: oh sorry if cookie isnt found should be:
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visited']))

Answer (score 1):

Try using this checkCookie function below

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}  

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var visited = getCookie("visited");
    if (visited != "") {
        // do whatever
    } else {
        setCookie("visited", "true", 30);
        window.location.href = '/welcome';
    }
}
```

For more information, I suggesting visiting [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Comment: @LewisMilburn - I edited my answer to add in the set cookie method on used on W3Schools